How to pass DaisyUI primary color to TailwindCSS config file?
I have a custom keyframe set in my tailwindcss config file.
  keyframes: {
        'grow-right-shorten-left': {
          '0%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -80px rgba(34, 211, 238, 0.4)' },
          '50%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -60px rgba(34, 211, 238, 0.4)' },
          '100%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -80px rgba(34, 211, 238, 0.4)' },
        }
    },

Instead of passing in the hardcoded RGBA color code, I want to extract the primary color that DaisyUI creates for when the theme is updated. Having some hard time with this, any tips are appreciated, thank you!
Ive tried a bunch of ways

You could use the CSS variable that Daisy UI generates like:
keyframes: {
  'grow-right-shorten-left': {
    '0%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -80px oklch(var(--p))' },
    '50%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -60px oklch(var(--p))' },
    '100%': { boxShadow: '30px 0px 100px -80px oklch(var(--p))' },
  }
},

Or you could use the theme() function to reference the color in the configuration like:
keyframes: {
  'grow-right-shorten-left': ({ theme }) => ({
    '0%': { boxShadow: `30px 0px 100px -80px ${theme('colors.primary')}` },
    '50%': { boxShadow: `30px 0px 100px -60px ${theme('colors.primary')}` },
    '100%': { boxShadow: `30px 0px 100px -80px ${theme('colors.primary')}` },
  }),
},


Youre a legend! The first answer was the key. thank you so much!
